# how to loop through array using ngFor in angular 11

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have a api responce like

res.attribute

```
0: {relate_id: 15, pid: 9, attr_slug: "size", items: "s,m,l", id: 1, …}
1: {relate_id: 16, pid: 9, attr_slug: "color", items: "yellow", id: 2, …}
length: 2
```

i need two set of radio buttons for size and color..i achived that through

```
 <section class="example-section"  *ngFor="let attr of Attr" >
      
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let checkbox of attr.items.split(',')" class="example-margin">{{checkbox}}</mat-radio-button>
    
    </section>
```

but, every radio button is like same name(only one from all 4 (s,m,l,yellow) can be selected)

what i am expecting is two different set of radio buttons like size and color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the input property `name` with the radio type you want.

```
[name]="attr.attr_slug"
```

This way it has a radio group that will be group by your slug name.

```
<section class="example-section"  *ngFor="let attr of Attr" >
      
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let checkbox of attr.items.split(',')" 
         [name]="attr.attr_slug"
         class="example-margin">{{checkbox}}</mat-radio-button>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: i need those two selected values ...how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `mat-radio-group` to group up the radio buttons inside. Try it like below :

```
<section class="example-section"  *ngFor="let attr of Attr" >
    <mat-radio-group [name]="attr.attr_slug">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let checkbox of attr.items.split(',')" class="example-margin">{{checkbox}}</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</section>
```

**Edit:**
For getting the desired  "s,yellow" or "m,yellow" output you can do a workaround below.

Since your slugs are size and color. Define a model has those properties in your component:

```
model = {
size = "",
color = "",
}
```

Bind the radio group to the corresponding properties  like below

```
<mat-radio-group [name]="attr.attr_slug" [value]="model[attr.attr_slug]">
```

So later in your component get your combined value like this :

```
const finalValue = `${this.model.size}, ${this.model.color}`
```

Comment: how to take selected values from this?

Comment: @Pugazh radio group has a property named `value` it gives you the selected value.

Comment: thanks , but i need  a value like "s,yellow" or "m,yellow" (refer api response)

Comment: i tried using (click)="onClick(checkbox)" , where i am getting recently clicked button..but i need a pair of size and color

Comment: sorry @Eldar ..i am getting nothing...i have raised a detailed question ..please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294497/how-to-get-value-from-radio-button-in-angular-11

Answer (score 0):

As @Eldar said you need to include `mat-radio-button` inside `mat-radio-group` then you have two different sets of radio button groups. You can refer to the Angular Material docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples#radio-ng-model).

Comment: how to take selected values from this