# how to get value from radio button in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, data-binding, ngfor

i have a API response like ,

```
0: {relate_id: 15, pid: 9, attr_slug: "size", items: "s,m,l", id: 1, …}
1: {relate_id: 16, pid: 9, attr_slug: "color", items: "yellow", id: 2, …}
length: 2
```

this is product's variety details..0: is for size..and 1:is for color (it may varry like kg,ram etc..)

i have radio buttons for this like,

```
 <section class="example-section"  *ngFor="let attr of Attr" >
      
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let checkbox of attr.items.split(',')" 
         [name]="attr.attr_slug"  (click)="onClick(checkbox)" [value]="model[attr.attr_slug]" 
          class="example-margin">{{checkbox}}</mat-radio-button>
    
    </section>
```

this onclick just giving the recent clicked ...but i need a pair of 1: & 2: like ("s,yellow) or ("m,yellow),..

i also tried with [value] and model as

```
model:any = {
  size : "",
  color : "",
  }
  finalValue = `${this.model.size}, ${this.model.color}`
```

but i get only ',' in console.log(this.finalvalue)...how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`mat-radio-group`](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api#MatRadioGroup) and use the `change` output to detect changes:

```
<section *ngFor="let attr of Attr" >
  <mat-radio-group [value]="model[attr.attr_slug]"
                   [name]="attr.attr_slug"
                   (change)="onRadioChange()">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let checkbox of attr.items.split(',')" 
                      [value]="checkbox">
      {{checkbox}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</section>
```

```
@ViewChildren(MatRadioGroup)
radios?: QueryList<MatRadioGroup>;

onRadioChange(): void {
  const value = this.radios?.map((radio) => radio.value).join(','); 
}
```

Comment: thanks..but i need a pair of values like "s,yellow" or "m,yellow" (refer API response)

Comment: @ radio === change.source ...(error)    This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'MatRadioGroup' and '_MatRadioButtonBase' have no overlap.

Comment: Property 'radios' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Comment: @barathkumar how about now?

Comment: thanks sir...i am new to angular...how i can tag you if i ask questions in S.Overflow...?

Comment: @barathkumar you can leave a comment here with a link :)